# desktop windows arrangement

Tags: display

I remember that Jeff was talking in a podcast about an utility which help him to send opened windows to certain zones of the screen, or resize them, just by using some keyboard combination. This seems to be verry useful, especially when you work on two monitors and you don't wana broke your work flow by talking the mouse, moving the window, coming back to keyboard.

Can you recommend me any of this type of applications?

ps: this might be a superuser.com question but this type of utility is more used on coders world, because they don't like to use mouse so much. That why I';m waiting an answer from you, from the programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Fusion supports this, and is invaluable to any dual monitor user.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) is also quite a handy tool